# PHP MongoDB $and / $all querying

Tags: php, mongodb

If I want to select documents that meet two specific criteria, how do I format the query? Right now I currently have this:

```
$params = array('$all' => array(
              array('parent.id'=>'1'),
              array('owner_id'=>'8')
          ));
$data = $collection->find($params);
```

This query brings me back no results...any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouh.. Use it:

```
$params = array('$all' => array(
              array('parent'=>array('id'=>'1')),
              array('owner_id'=>8)
          ));
$data = $collection->find($params);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate it! How does this differ from this: $params = array('parent.id'=>1, 'owner_id'=>8);

Comment: MongoDB is JSON database. Is db for _objects_ and for sub element use select in object.

Answer (score 1):

parent.id is integer?

Maybe that:

```
$params = array('$all' => array(
              array('parent.id'=>1),
              array('owner_id'=>8)
          ));
$data = $collection->find($params);
```

Comment: No, they are strings. Querying find(array('parent.id'=>1)) and find(array('owner_id'=>8)) separately works fine, I need to combine them though so that I receive back all documents that have a parent ID of one AND an owner id of 8

Comment: Holy crap I'm an idiot. The correct way to do this is: $params = array('parent.id'=>1, 'owner_id'=>8);